# What would Born's rule look like if it were to the power three?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, born-rule, quantum-foundations

In matrix notation, the probability that some quantum state $\hat{\rho}$ is measured along some projector $\hat{\Pi}_k$ is
\begin{equation}
p_k = \mbox{Tr}\{\hat{\Pi}_k \hat{\rho}\}.
\end{equation}

I'd like to keep using the matrix notation without having to work with the individual ket-bra components. What would this generalized Born's rule, which cubes the probability amplitudes as opposed to squaring them, look like?

PS: For more context, the reason I'm asking is inspired by [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1190545) on the experimental verification of the squared character of Born's rule.